# Is There any way to read the URL query param along with page request in application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

There a webpage which accepts an `?id=` URL parameter lets say like this
https://localhost/report.cfm?id=34
I want to give access to the user if the id is a valid report id.

Is there any way I can get the value of that id parameter which is passed to page inside Application.cfc.
If that doesn't point to a valid id, I should be able to show an error page like 404 with the help of OnError function in coldfusion.

Comment: `onRequestStart` is the event you are looking for in your `Application.cfc`. There you can check for `structKeyExists(URL, "id") and (URL.id eq "34")` etc.

Comment: I nominate @Alex to answer the question.

Comment: There are different ways to accomplish this, but you should output a 404 status code using cfheader. Instead of doing it globally in application.cfc, which could cause problems if you expand the use of url.id in your app, you could do it in the page that’s expecting the url.id param, which also needs to do a sql lookup on the same id. So you would eliminate an extra lookup.

Comment: Thanks so much.. @Redtopia for such a good advice I'll do that .